# n_jobs for sklearn multioutput regressor with estimator=random forest regressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, random-forest

How should `:param n_jobs:` be used when both the [random forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) estimator for [multioutput regressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html) and the multioutput regressor itself both have it? For example, is it better to not specify `n_jobs` for the estimator, but set `n_jobs` for the multioutput regressor? Several examples are shown below:

```py
# Imports
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor

# (1) No parallelization
rf_no_jobs = RandomForestRegressor()
multioutput_no_jobs_alpha = MultiOutputRegressor(estimator=rf_no_jobs)

# (2) RF w/ parallelization, multioutput w/o parallelization
rf_with_jobs = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=-1)
multioutput_no_jobs_beta = MultiOutputRegressor(estimator=rf_with_jobs)

# (3) RF w/o parallelization, multioutput w parallelization
multioutput_with_jobs_alpha = MultiOutputRegressor(estimator=rf_no_jobs, n_jobs=-1)

# (4) Both parallelized
multioutput_with_jobs_beta = MultiOutputRegressor(estimator=rf_with_jobs, n_jobs=-1)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out an optimum for this? - thanks

Comment: I did not investigate it further, no. It was for a research project and there were other things that I was concerned about optimizing, so I did not return to this. One way to check it might be to use the `timeit` library, I'm not 100% sure, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `RandomForestRegressor` has 'native' multioutput support (no need for the multioutput wrapper), I instead looked at the `KNeighborsRegressor` and `LightGBM` which have an inner `n_jobs` argument and about which I had the same question.

Running on a Ryzen 5950X (Linux) and Intel 11800H (Windows), both with n_jobs = 8, I found consistent results:

- With low Y dimensionality (say, 1 - 10 targets) it doesn't matter much where n_jobs goes, it finishes quickly regardless. Initializing multiprocessing has a ~1 second overhead, but joblib will reuse existing pools by default, speeding things up.
- With high dimensionality (say > 20) placing n_jobs only in the `MultiOutputRegressor` with KNN receiving n_jobs=1 is **10x faster** at 160 dimensions/targets.
- Using `with joblib.parallel_backend("loky", n_jobs=your_n_jobs):` was equally fast and conveniently sets the n_jobs for all sklearn things inside. This is the easy option.
- `RegressorChain` is fast enough at low dimensionality but gets ridiculously slow (**500x slower** vs Multioutput) with 160 dimensions for KNeighbors (I would stick to `LightGBM` for use with the `RegressorChain` which performs better).
- With `LightGBM`, `MultiOutputRegressor` only setting n_jobs was again faster than the inner n_jobs, but the difference was much smaller (5950x Linux the difference was 3x, 11800H Windows only 1.2x).

Since the full code gets a bit long, here is a partial sample that gets most of it:

```py
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import numpy as np
from joblib import parallel_backend
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor, RegressorChain
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing

# adjust n_jobs to the number of physical CPU cores on your machine or pass -1 for auto max
n_jobs = 8
knn_model_param_dict = {}  # kwargs if desired
num_y_dims = 160

X, y_one_dim = fetch_california_housing(return_X_y=True)
y_one_dim = y_one_dim.reshape(-1, 1)
# extra multioutput dims generated randomly
dims = [y_one_dim]
for _ in range(num_y_dims - 1):
    dims.append(np.random.gamma(y_one_dim.std(), size=y_one_dim.shape))
y = np.concatenate(dims, axis=1)


# INIT
regr = MultiOutputRegressor(
    KNeighborsRegressor(**knn_model_param_dict),
    n_jobs=n_jobs,
).fit(X, y)

trial = "KNN with all n_jobs=1"
start = timer()
regr = MultiOutputRegressor(
    KNeighborsRegressor(**knn_model_param_dict, n_jobs=1),
    n_jobs=1,
)
regr.fit(X, y)
regr.predict(X)
end = timer()
print(f"trial: {trial} with runtime: {end - start}")

trial = "KNN inner model with n_jobs"
start = timer()
regr = MultiOutputRegressor(
    KNeighborsRegressor(**knn_model_param_dict, n_jobs=n_jobs),
    n_jobs=1,
)
regr.fit(X, y)
regr.predict(X)
end = timer()
print(f"trial: {trial} with runtime: {end - start}")

trial = "KNN outer multioutput with n_jobs, inner with 1"
start = timer()
regr = MultiOutputRegressor(
    KNeighborsRegressor(**knn_model_param_dict, n_jobs=1),
    n_jobs=n_jobs,
)
regr.fit(X, y)
regr.predict(X)
end = timer()
print(f"trial: {trial} with runtime: {end - start}")

trial = "KNN inner and outer both -1"
start = timer()
regr = MultiOutputRegressor(
    KNeighborsRegressor(**knn_model_param_dict, n_jobs=-1),
    n_jobs=-1,
)
regr.fit(X, y)
regr.predict(X)
end = timer()
print(f"trial: {trial} with runtime: {end - start}")

trial = "joblib backend chooses"
start = timer()
with parallel_backend("loky", n_jobs=n_jobs):
    regr = MultiOutputRegressor(
        KNeighborsRegressor(**knn_model_param_dict),
    )
    regr.fit(X, y)
    regr.predict(X)
end = timer()
```

Comment: For experiments/ML data analytics on large-scale datasets, it's better to use more CPUs/computing capacity to speed up training the individual estimator (for per target/y). E.g., with X_train of size 1M x 1K and y_train of size 1M x 4, on a Mac with 12 CPUs+32GB memory, one could allocate 6 CPUs for each Lightgbm / XGBoost model, use n_jobs=2 for MultiOutputRegressor(estimator, *, n_jobs=2). This would help you get the results faster, this is especially true if you use Optuna to tune hyperparameters for Lightgbm / XGBoost models on large-scale datasets.